# TemplateDoesNotExist at /product/1/ productDetail.html

Tags: python, django

I am making an about page for every item.
There is a problem that occurred when I am pressing 'View' on my store page: **TemplateDoesNotExist at /product/1/
productDetail.html**

I have tried specifying the directory by putting {{% extends store/main.html %}}, it did not help.
Please assist me.

store/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import datetime

from django.urls import reverse

from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import *
from .utils import cookieCart, cartData, guestOrder


def store(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)


def cart(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)


def checkout(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)


def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)


def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    else:
        customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)

    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id

    if total == order.get_cart_total:
        order.complete = True
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            address=data['shipping']['address'],
            city=data['shipping']['city'],
            state=data['shipping']['state'],
            zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
        )

    return JsonResponse('Payment submitted..', safe=False)


def productDetail(request, pk):
    eachProduct = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    num_comments = Comment.objects.filter(product=eachProduct).count()

    context = {
        'eachProduct': eachProduct,
        'num_comments': num_comments,
    }

    return render(request, 'productDetail.html', context)

def add_comment(request, pk):
    eachProduct = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = CommentForm(instance=eachProduct)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=eachProduct)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.user.username
            body = form.cleaned_data['comment_body']
            c = Comment(product=eachProduct, commenter_name=name, comment_body=body, date_added=datetime.now())
            c.save()
            return redirect('showProducts')
        else:
            print('form is invalid')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()


    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'add_comment.html', context)

def delete_comment(request, pk):
    comment = Comment.objects.filter(product=pk).last()
    product_id = comment.product.id
    comment.delete()
    return redirect(reverse('product', args=[product_id]))
```

sotre/urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Leave as empty string for base url
    path('', views.store, name="store"),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name="cart"),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),

    path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name="update_item"),
    path('process_order/', views.processOrder, name="process_order"),

    path('product/<int:pk>/', views.productDetail, name='product'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/add-comment', views.add_comment, name='add-comment'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/delete-comment', views.delete_comment, name='delete-comment'),

]
```

[why am I getting this error, if productDetail exists?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts45d.png)

Comment: You missed the parent directory like `store/productDetail.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template path is incorrect, since your template is inside the store directory you have to specify a relative path to templates.

Change this

```
return render(request, 'productDetail.html', context)
```

to

```
return render(request, 'store/productDetail.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue

Comment: I know that this not related question, but perhaps you could give me a clue about what direction should I go? After I have changed the return, another error risen: NoReverseMatch at /product/1/
Reverse for 'showProducts' not found. 'showProducts' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @ArtemiiKhristich You wrote `redirect('showProducts')` but there are no url definitions with that name. Also if this answer resolved your original issue please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.